# Kafka streams didn׳t balance the work

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We work with Kafka streams and always just 3 of our 20 instances work with 80%-90% CPU and because that our consumer lag is very hight.
Our config is 8 threads per instances and we have 150 input partitions

Comment: Could it be that most of your input data is, for example, in only 3 of the 150 partitions?  Or, if your processing is computationally expensive, that the data in a few partitions require much more CPU than the data in the other (many) partitions?

Comment: We Don't work with a key so the data need to be produced with a round robin method. I don't know if it is relevant to this kind of issue but we have **Join** in the process.

Comment: Perhaps check then whether any data imbalances (if it's not in the input) can be observed in later processing stages, like the join or after the join.

Comment: It is difficult to help with the little information you shared.